# add Xcode target in git repository

Tags: xcode

I am working on an iOS project.
I have checked source control support (git) at project creation.

I have add a target for apple watch. In fact Xcode created 2 targets: watch app and watch app extension.

My problem is i was supposed to see a letter (A) in project tree but i do not see nothing next to new files.

How can i add those new folders and files in git ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
git add -A
```

This command will add all new changes in the current repository. To run it just open Terminal and go to your Xcode project folder and type it in. You can then see the added changes with `git status`

Comment: Are you sure it will takes effect on subdirectories ? And all files should not be in git (temporary files) ? Thanks